# didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message Not Running Actual Device

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am working on a chat app.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{}
```

This method is working and getting caught buy break point while running in Simulator when it  **App is Background**

But While running in the app in Real Device App in

> background mode . its not working in background mode

Comment: Did you check in your app `Capabilities` if you selected `Background Modes` ON?

Comment: Yes it ON, i have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
```

in your

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

then this method

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{}
```

will work in Background also.

For more information about BackgroundTask, please visit the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)

Comment: Thanks @user5633758 for posting question! +1.